# Msbuild does not recognize mapped network drive

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2008, network-drive

We have a project that builds and has a post build event. The post build event copies the output DLL to a directory F. The system is supposed to place all DLLs in the F drive. In my system, I cannot partition my drive to add an F drive, so I mapped a dummy F folder to be the F drive.

```
F drive -> \\<PC IP>\C$\F\
```

When I build the solution using Visual Studio 2008 the post build event is successful. But when I try to build the solution using command line msbuild, it fails and says that the "Specified drive does not exist". Any idea how to trick the powershell into believing the F drive exist? I can navigate to the F drive using Windows explorer properly and as I said earlier the post build event succeeds when using the IDE.

The powershell command line used:

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Note that my system is a Windows 7 Professional. I tried to do the same msbuild using Windows XP and there is no problem. I ran the command prompt with Administrator rights too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fake a drive letter on a local computer use `SUBST` instead of mapping a network drive.

From `Subst /?`:

```
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.
```

So you should be able to use something like `c:\> subst F: C:\F`.

Also ensure you are subst'ing the drive (or mapping it) in the same user space as Powershell/MSBuild is running in.  If you map a drive as the local user, and MSBuild is running 'as Administrator' it won't be able to see your user mapped drive (and vise versa).